# AWS CloudSearch words broken with spaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, amazon-cloudsearch

Is there a way to query CloudSearch to also search, or disregard spaces that could break a word into two? For example, if I search "starwars" vs. "star wars", I would like to return similar results. I hoped a fuzzy match would accomplish this, but it doesn't seem to be so.